# Checking DOM element node Types

Tags: javascript, html, css

This exercise will be to write a helper script that could theoretically be used on any web page to help identify the elements that contain text, simply by including your JavaScript file!

1. Define the script in a source file called highlightNodes.js.
2. This script should navigate every element in the DOM, and for each element in the body determine whether it is a  element ( type 3) or not.
3. Now add to your script code to create a new child node for every non-text node encountered. This new node should take on the class " hoverNode" and innerHTML equal to the parent tag name. Define appropriate styles for that CSS class.
4. Now add listeners so that when you click on the newly created nodes, they will alert you to information about the tag name, so that when a node is clicked a pop- up alerts us to the details about that node including its ID and innerHTML.

The example picture that the teacher took it really poor quality, but I think you will still be able to see what's going on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNMit.jpg

Here's the code I have so far:  https://jsfiddle.net/vuku3qdu/2/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var bodyNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < bodyNodes.length; i++) {
        if (bodyNodes[i].nodeType != 3) {
            newChildNode = document.createElement("p");
            newChildNode.className = "hoverNode";
            newChildNode.innerHTML = bodyNodes[i].tagName;
            bodyNodes[i].appendChild(newChildNode);
            newChildNode.addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert("Tag Name: " + newChildNode.tagName + "  innerHtml: " + newChildNode.innerHTML);
            });

        }

        i++;
    }
};*
```

For some reason, this isn't working on Jfiddle correctly.  It displays highlight nodes locally.  My issue is that it isn't evaluating the nodeTypes properly.  It is saying that they are all "1" for NodeType.  I know this isn't correct and it's giving me too many of these highlight nodes.  Also, it is skipping the "label" elements that are embedded within the Fieldset.

My last problem... I can't get the Highlight nodes to output the proper newChildNodes.innerHTML in the listener functions.  It always gives me undefined.

I've logged all of the steps through the console and I know that it is evaluating the node types wrong, but I cannot figure out the correct command to do so.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Are you paying for your classes?

Comment: This is the clearest example of a "homework" question I've ever seen, but at least no attempt to hide that fact was made and OP did try to figure it out on his/her own.  Here is a trimmed down jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c53xa9ar/.  The first one did not work for me.